# What is this most likely if not Lua bytecode?

Tags: lua, bytecode

I considered posting this in reverse engineering but because of the brevity of the question and general irrelevance I decided to post it here.

This may be a really easy question but I haven't been able to find an answer - I should probably read a bit of Lua's source before asking this, but here goes: in a program that has integrated Lua, this is the first few bytes of the buffer being executed:

```
11 16 A5 F1 9E A8 8B 64 78 8E 2F EA 1C 31 D3 B6 D3 D5 77 23 77 79 1B 73
```

I've never understood Lua very well, but that doesn't look like byte code. Is there anything else it could be or is it just certainly something custom? I'm pretty sure actual Lua opcodes haven't been modified.

Comment: Please show a command to execute this buffer.

Answer (score 1):

if possible put whole file somewhere. Lua bytecode usualy starts with 1B 4C 75 61 and then some debug infos however there are zeros for spliting of the informations which your sample doesnt have
other way is asking on http://forum.xentax.com/

Answer (score 0):

Put this into a file and try running `luac -l filename` on it. This will disassemble the binary to the VM instructions.

If it is Lua code you'll get some meaningful output.